# Getopt::Long: Detect if no Options Passed

Tags: perl, default, getopt-long

How to detect if no options were passed to a script using the [`GetOpt::Long`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) module?

For instance to output script usage (help) with [`pod2usage()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod::Usage) by default (when the script is called without options).

This general solution doesn't work (because options are not considered arguments):

```perl
if (@ARGV == 0) {
  ...
}
```

---

I found a related question that was asked 10 years ago, but it seems to be ambiguous (module not specified [ though looks like to be `Getopt::Std` ], the case with subroutine runs asked specifically), poorly written, and closed.

[Best way to run subroutine if no options provided? Perl getOpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359386/best-way-to-run-subroutine-if-no-options-provided-perl-getopt)

---

Tried to read on return values:

https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Return-values-and-Errors

Tried to do via @ARGV == 0 as indicated above

Comment: You could compare the size of `@ARGV` before and after the `GetOptions` call?

Comment: @JimDavis but that's not an elegant way, isn't there a built-in option for that purpose (which might be a very common thing to check)?

Comment: @toolic also that solution you mentioned (ie. `if (%options) { ... } `) didn't work for me.

Comment: The hash cannot be empty / return false because its keys are defined in advance with the standard usage of `Getops::Long`.

Comment: The specificity is it's related to a single Perl distribution only (see the tag) to see if it's possible to detect that case using that distribution proper or its provided tools.

Comment: @Elvin Re: _"that's not an elegant way"_ - Why not? ... and I don't think it's very common to check if no options have been used. Most program does not require optional arguments to run a default configuration.

Comment: @TedLyngmo because the solution is not being provided by the module itself, I thought it could return some value indicating this very case. "Common", because of the default Usage help message which is a de-facto standard throughout many Unix utilities.

Comment: @Elvin It's very common to print USAGE if the non-optional arguments are not fulfilled.  That is, first call `GetOptions` and then check if `@ARGV == 2` if there are two non-optional arguments. The information you need is there (by comparing `@ARGV` before and after) and I guess not many people have requested that to be made more elegant. Probably because it's rarely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers and further reading elsewhere:

I set my current solution to the following code snippet:

```perl
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;

my $options;

my $argv_before_options = @ARGV; # Record somewhere

Getopt::Long::Parser
  -> new( config => [ 'bundling', 'no_ignore_case' ] )
    -> getoptions(
        'quite|q' => \$options{quite},
        'help|h' => \$options{help},
       );

my $argv_after_options = @ARGV; # Record for readability

my $options_not_specified =
  $argv_after_getopts == $argv_before_getopts; # Boolean, holding as a variable for readability

if ($options_not_specified or $options{help}) { # Default or -h
  pod2usage();
}
```

Which I'm satisfied about, although wishing [Getopt-Long](https://metacpan.org/dist/Getopt-Long) could have this detection built-in as a return value of some of its method.

Maybe, it's time for a new [PR](https://github.com/sciurius/perl-Getopt-Long)?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways:

- Check if `@ARGV` has the same number of elements before and after the call to `GetOptions`. If so, no options were passed.

  ```perl
  my $num_args = @ARGV;

  GetOptions( ... )
     or usage();

  my $num_non_opt_args = @ARGV;
  if ( $num_args == $num_non_opt_args  ) {
     ...
  }
  ```
- Before calling `GetOptions`, check if `$ARGV[0]` starts with `-` or `+` (since `GetOptions` allows options to start by `-`, `--` and `+` by default). If so, an option was passed.

  ```perl
  if ( !( @ARGV && $ARGV[0] =~ /^-/ ) ) {
     ...
  }

  Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default ));  # Disalllow `+opt`, for one.
  GetOptions( ... )
     or usage();
  ```

Both of the above methods count the option terminator `--` as an option. If this isn't acceptable, check if the first element of `@ARGV` is `--` and compensate.

---

That said, it usually makes more sense to check for specific options, which is done by checking if the variables associated with them are defined.

```perl
use File::Basename qw( basename );

sub usage {
   if ( @_ ) {
      my $msg = shift;
      chomp( $msg );
      warn( "$msg\n" );
   }

   my $prog = basename( $0 );
   warn( "Use `$prog --help` for help.\n" );
   exit( 1 );
}

usage( "Either `-x` or `-y` must be provided." )
   if !defined( $opt_x ) && !defined( $opt_y );
```

Answer (score 2):

Because options start with either `-`, `--` or `+`, you can check `@ARGV` for any element that resembles one of those. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

if (! _options_present(@ARGV)) {
    help();
}

my %args;

GetOptions (
    'd|directory=s' => \$args{directory},
    'f|file=s'      => \$args{file},
);

sub help {
    print "You need to send in options!\n";
    exit;
}

sub _options_present {
    my (@args) = @_;
    my $option_present = grep /^(?:--?|\+)\w+/, @args;
    return $option_present;
}
```